# find out which computer has opened a file on Servers network share

Tags: windows, network-shares

I have a Windows Server 2008 and it shares a folder. Many clients access that folder and the inherit files. One client opens one dll file 
sporadically with mode rw, so after that no other client can load the dll.

Now I want to determine which client does it. All tools I found:

- openfile
- net
- sharewatch
- NetShareMonitor

doesn't show me the Network client which opens the file in rw mode.

I think it is the antivirus programm, but I need to know which client has the file opend.

Edit:

- The clients are windows machines
- All clients use the same user, so I can't determine the client with the username

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by client?

Comment: a client is a PC with a win7, win8 or win10 OS

Answer (score 4):

This may be of use to you:

[image]

I can't be certain it's the same location on Server edition, but I accessed it through <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> -> `Computer Management` -> `System Tools` -> `Shared Folders` -> `Open Files`

This lists each open file handle, its "Open Mode" (Read/ReadWrite) and the user. You can also close the file handle from this location.

Comment: Yes, I know that dialog, but I can't determine the name (or IP) of the client-PC.I only know the user, and the user is always the same.

Comment: @Biber Compare the list against `net session` from CMD, which should tell you which IP address a user is coming from.

Comment: The user is always the same, so I can't compare anything,..

Comment: @Biber Ah, okay. This makes things difficult, as I believe the file is locked against a user. Sorry, I don't know a way to narrow that down.

Comment: For your reference, you can right click the list and close the session if the file is locked. This page is not view only :)

Comment: @Bilo I did include that in the last sentence, but thank you ;)

Answer (score 4):

We have been wanting to do this for years!

Today we spotted this utility:

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_opened_files.html

Fantastic!

Edit:

You can use NetworkOpenedFiles from Nirsoft to determine which host has an open file on a Windows file share.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but nevertheless:

if you have PowerShell 4.0+ (which does not come with Windows Server 2008, you would have to update your PowerShell Version), you could use this:

Directly on the server:

```
Get-SmbOpenFile | where-object { $_.Path -like 'C:\foo\bar\*' }
```

from a RemoteMachine:

```
$cim = New-CimSession ServerName -Credential (get-credential)
Get-SmbOpenFile -CimSession $cim | where-object { $_.Path -like 'C:\foo\bar\*' }
```

`Get-SmbOpenfile` returns a list of all open files on the server, which we filter with `where-object` to only see the ones we're looking for.

This will return amongst other things the `ClientComputerName` which is the IP of the computer that has opened the file.

Here's an example output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-smbopenfile -cimsession $cim | where-object { $_.Path -like 'D:\Daten\Transfer\*' }

    FileId       SessionId    Path                 ShareRelativePath ClientComputerName ClientUserName PSComputerName
    ------       ---------    ----                 ----------------- ------------------ -------------- --------------
    347355680805 348160786757 D:\Daten\TRANSFER\xy TRANSFER\xy       10.0.0.114         INTERNAL\xy    Server
```

If you then want to quickly see what's the hostname of the returned IP-Address, use:

```
[Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress("10.0.0.114") | select -expand HostName
```